# Flat paper shadow in React native, how to achieve?

Tags: react-native

> I am new to react native and I want to create a show of a view. I am
>   attaching the image below:-

[image: slice of my view]

For the solution I just thought that I would append a Image similar to the shadow, but is there any other way to create this by using any stylesheet?

My view code with css I am giving here
.

```
<View style={{width: '100%', height: 90, flexDirection:'row',marginBottom:15,flex:1}}>
   <View style={{flex:2,backgroundColor:"#388E3C"}}></View>
   <View style={{flex:5,backgroundColor:"#66BB6A"}}></View>
</View>
```

My full screen is here:-

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create a shadow of the view you should use:

```
const shadowStyle = {

shadowColor: "#000",
shadowOffset: {
    width: 0,
    height: 5,
},
shadowOpacity: 0.34,
shadowRadius: 6.27,

elevation: 10,
}
<View style={shadowStyle}/>
```